# How do you direct webbooks notifications in Azure Devops to Outlook?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-devops, office365, webhooks

To be more precise, I want to set up Azure DevOps to receive webhook notifications from another software then, take that webhook notification and direct it to Outlook? Is this possible?

Comment: Hi @Xcer, do you mind sharing more details about scenario? Such as notification type and another software name? It seems that cannot do this, If you could share more details here, it can help provide a workaround. By the way, you can also try to send notification to outlook via power automate

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thanks for responding! I'm trying to set up Azure DevOps to receive webhook notification from Anchore which is used to scan images in a Kubernetes cluster. Anchore sends alert as a webhook therefore, I want to set up Azure DevOps to receives this webhook notification then direct it to outlook.

Comment: Hi @Xcer, Do you have to set up Azure DevOps to receive Webhook notifications from Anchorage? I found a workaround and share it in the answer, please check it and then kindly share the result here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Xcer, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thanks for the reply! I've been working on another project so I'm not working on this issue atm. But When I get back to it, ill give you an update. Sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, maybe you can try it with [power automate](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) such as below.

[image]